# How to integrate Ember-CLI application into Grails plugin

Tags: grails, ember.js, ember-cli

Can somebody tell me, how to integrate the Ember-CLI dist-folder into a Grails plugin? My plan is to have a Grails application that could be extended by grails plugins. A plugin should contain a Grails server (with REST-services) and an Ember-CLI  client. The Ember-CLI *.hbs should be displayed in the content area of the main grails application.

Comment: I use grails as my backend, but my Ember application is completely separate from the grails project. The two communicate over a RESTful JSON api

Comment: I had it like this in a test project, it work good. But now i need the Ember-CLI frontend integrated in the plugin.